# The Jacobi-Davidson method

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

Does any implementation of the [Jacobi-Davidson method](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036144599363084) for *Mathematica* exist? A highly parallelized version for sparse matrices would be of special interest.

Comment: As an alternative, you could perhaps convert the Matlab code (http://www.math.uu.nl/~sleij101/) or call it in Matlab from Mathematica, or use Matlab, or try Fortran 77 http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~jadamilu/ . Are you restricted to Mathematica only?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering whether a ready-to-use Mathematica implementation existed.